# PHP file_exists($var) not working

Tags: php, file-io

I'm trying to write some code on my notebook and am using the xampp environment. I have the following piece of code:

```
class A {
...
  foreach ($blocks as $block) {
    $block = 'dir/dir2/' . $block;
  }
  if (file_exists($block) == true) {
    $var .= file_get_contents($block);
  }
}
```

When I echo the $block variable in the foreach loop, it gives back the path to the files. However, the file_exists function always returns false. Could you please help me figure out what's wrong here?

Answer (score 8):

`file_exists` purpose is to check if the supplied file exists. It's returning false. This means that the your file doesn't exist where php is looking. php might be looking in a different area than you expect. Looks like it's time for some debugging.

Run this to figure out where php is looking.

```
echo "current working directory is -> ". getcwd();
```

Is that where you want php to look? If not then change the directory php is looking in with the `chdir` function.

```
$searchdirectory = "c:\path\to\your\directory"; //use unix style paths if necessary
chdir($searchdirectory);
```

Then run your function (note: I flipped the slashes to backslashes in order to be consistent with windows style paths.)

```
class A {
...
  //change working directory
  $searchdirectory = "c:\path\to\your\directory"; //use unix style paths if necessary
  chdir($searchdirectory);

  foreach ($blocks as $block) {
    $block = 'dir\dir2\' . $block;

    if (file_exists($block) == true) {
      $var .= file_get_contents($block);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Quoting someones comment on the php `file_exists` manual page,

> Be aware: If you pass a relative path
>   to file_exists, it will return false
>   unless the path happens to be relative
>   to the "current PHP dir" (see chdir()
>   ).

In other words, if your path is relative to the current files directory, you should append `dirname(__FILE__)` to your relative paths, or as of PHP 5.3, you can just use `__DIR__`.

Comment: TJM, if I add DIR, the echo gives me "C:\xampp\htdocs/dir/dir2" and the file_exists still doesn't work.

Comment: @Alex you're mixing unix and windows style paths, use `dir\dir2\` instead

Comment: Ah yeah, I assumed linux based on your paths, as onteria_ says, changing your path separator should fix it.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for a totally dumb question but what would be the best way to do that so that I won't have to rewrite the slashes when I deploy the code on the server?

Comment: @Alex - use a `$path_delimiter` variable and set it to which slash you want to use. `$path_delimiter = ($unix) ? "/" : "\" ;`

Comment: @jeremysawesome @Alex the [`DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php) constant

Comment: @Wiseguy - I'd not heard of the `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant. Your wisdom is truly magnificent.

Answer (score 1):

It may be too late but just found its solution after banging my head for last 2 hrs. In case you are using windows, it hides file name extension by default. So `a.txt` will be displayed as `a` and the file which is displayed as `a.txt` is actually `a.txt.txt` . To view file extensions go to 
**Control Panel -> Appereances And Personalization -> Folder Option -> View**
and uncheck  **hide file name extension**. Now you can see the true name which is to be used in file_exists().

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing slashes, this one drove me nuts.

Here is the solution:

```
echo getcwd();
$searchimg = getcwd().'\\public\\images\\pics\\'.$value['name'].'.'.$value['ext'];
```

You will need to quote the slashes like that all the way to the picture :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, you are using `file_exists` outside the `foreach` loop. Hence the `$block` variable is not bound at the time.

EDIT: actually it is still bound to the last value in your collection.

Comment: [It *is* bound](http://codepad.org/sF6BAW8D), but it holds the value of the last iteration in the loop. This item happens not to exist, so it appears that `file_exists` "always" returns false.

Comment: Thanks, Tomalak, indeed it holds the last value!

Comment: TJM, if I add __DIR__, the echo gives me "C:\xampp\htdocs/dir/dir2" and the file_exists still doesn't work.

Comment: @Alex: Then the path doesn't exist. Not a huge surprise since you're mixing slashes.

Comment: Thanks, Tomalak. Trying to figure out how to change the slashes when calling __DIR__ without having to recode everything when I deploy the code online.

Answer (score 0):

Do you intend to check `file_exists()` inside the foreach loop?

```
class A {
  ...
  foreach ($blocks as $block) {
    $block = 'dir/dir2/' . $block;

    // Inside the loop      
    if (file_exists($block) == true) {
      $var .= file_get_contents($block);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, Michael. That's the idea.

Answer (score 0):

i guess that the check of file_exists work a bit different from opening with file_get_contents. so i maye it could be one of these problems:

- file_exists: returns FALSE if inaccessible due to safe mode restrictions
- file_exists: for checking it uses the real UID/GID and not the effective rights
- file_get_contents: uses a protocol with file_exists does not know..

maybe it helps you further! good luck

Answer (score -1):

If you use a variable for your file, make sure that there are no blank space at the end. I went mad until i found the solution : removing blank with trim(). See below.

```
if file_exists(trim($Filename))
```